# Flux.generate with Consumer and parallel

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have simple Flux

```
Flux<Long> flux = Flux.generate(
            AtomicLong::new,
            (state, sink) -> {
                long i = state.getAndIncrement();
                sink.next(i);
                if (i == 3) sink.complete();
                return state;
            }, (state) -> System.out.println("state: " + state));
```

Which works as expected in a single thread:

```
flux.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

The output is

```
0 1 2 3 state: 4
```

But when I switch to parallel:

```
flux.parallel().runOn(Schedulers.elastic()).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

The Consumer which should print state: Number isn't invoked. I just see:

```
0 3 2 1
```

Is it a bug or expected feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a reactive expert but after digging into the source code it seems that the behavior is by design; it seems that creating a ParallelFlux has the side effect of blocking the call of the State Consumer; if you want to go parallel and getting the State Consumer invoked you can use:

```java
flux.publishOn(Schedulers.elastic()).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Got it. But it strange behavior when you create a Flux and expect some result but using it somewhere in the code can change this behavior.